# the anchor by default

Tags: google-maps-api-3

By default, the anchor of an icon created with MarkerImage is located along the center point of the bottom of the icon.
How to indicate we want to use the default value ?

```
var icon= new g.MarkerImage('images/house.png',
                new g.Size(32, 32),
                new g.Point(0,0),
                new g.Point(16, 32));
```

or

```
var icon= new g.MarkerImage('images/house.png',
                new g.Size(32, 32),
                new g.Point(0,0),
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

The anchor point is optional so you can choose to specify it in the constructor or not.  Up to you.  Either way should work.